# conditional expression in kivy lang

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to chance the opacity of a button through "on-press" function. For example, on the kv file code below, I want to chance the opacity of the button (bt1) by pressing the Button A. 
So, by pressing the Button A it should check if the opacity of (bt1) is equal to 0, if its true, change it to 1, if its false it should change the opacity of (bt2) from 0 to 1. Any idea how to do it? Thanks in advance.

```
FloatLayout:
    size_hint: None, None

    Button:
        id: bt1
        pos: 200, 300
        opacity: 0
        on_press: self.opacity = 0
    Button:
        id: bt2
        pos: 300, 300
        opacity: 0
        on_press: self.opacity = 0
    Button:
        id: bt3
        pos: 400, 300
        opacity: 0
        on_press: self.opacity = 0

    Button:
        pos: 0, 0
        text: 'A'
        on_press:
            bt3.opacity = 1 if bt2.opacity == 1 else 0
            bt2.opacity = 1 if bt1.opacity == 1 else 0
            bt1.opacity = 1 if bt1.opacity == 0 else 1


    Button:
        pos: 100, 0
        text: 'B'
        on_press:
            bt3.opacity = 1 if bt2.opacity == 1 else 0
            bt2.opacity = 1 if bt1.opacity == 1 else 0
            bt1.opacity = 1 if bt1.opacity == 0 else 1

    Button:
        pos: 200, 0
        text: 'C'
        on_press:
            bt3.opacity = 1 if bt2.opacity == 1 else 0
            bt2.opacity = 1 if bt1.opacity == 1 else 0
            bt1.opacity = 1 if bt1.opacity == 0 else 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use `if...elif...`.

## Solution - Change Button's Text

When button A is pressed, check if bt1's text is an empty string. If it's true then change bt1's text to 'A'. When button B is pressed, check if bt2's text is an empty string. If it is true then change bt2's text to 'B'.

### Snippets

```
Button:
    pos: 0, 0
    text: 'A'
    on_press:
        print("Button {} pressed".format(self.text))
        print("\tlen(bt1.text)={}".format(len(bt1.text)))

        # Assign Text
        if len(bt1.text) == 0: bt1.text = self.text
        elif len(bt2.text) == 0: bt2.text = self.text 

        # Assign Opacity
        if bt2.opacity == 1: bt3.opacity = 1
        elif bt1.opacity == 1: bt2.opacity = 1
        elif bt1.opacity == 0: bt1.opacity = 1

Button:
    pos: 100, 0
    text: 'B'
    on_press:
        print("Button {} pressed".format(self.text))
        print("\tlen(bt1.text)={}".format(len(bt1.text)))

        # Assign Text
        if len(bt1.text) == 0: bt1.text = self.text
        elif len(bt2.text) == 0: bt2.text = self.text 

        # Assign Opacity
        if bt2.opacity == 1: bt3.opacity = 1
        elif bt1.opacity == 1: bt2.opacity = 1
        elif bt1.opacity == 0: bt1.opacity = 1
```

### Example - Change Button's Text

#### main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
FloatLayout:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 100

    Button:
        id: bt1
        pos: 200, 300
        opacity: 0
        on_press: self.opacity = 0

    Button:
        id: bt2
        pos: 300, 300
        opacity: 0
        on_press: self.opacity = 0

    Button:
        id: bt3
        pos: 400, 300
        opacity: 0
        on_press: self.opacity = 0

    Button:
        pos: 0, 0
        text: 'A'
        on_press:
            print("Button {} pressed".format(self.text))
            print("\tlen(bt1.text)={}".format(len(bt1.text)))

            # Assign Text
            if len(bt1.text) == 0: bt1.text = self.text
            elif len(bt2.text) == 0: bt2.text = self.text 

            # Assign Opacity
            if bt2.opacity == 1: bt3.opacity = 1
            elif bt1.opacity == 1: bt2.opacity = 1
            elif bt1.opacity == 0: bt1.opacity = 1

    Button:
        pos: 100, 0
        text: 'B'
        on_press:
            print("Button {} pressed".format(self.text))
            print("\tlen(bt1.text)={}".format(len(bt1.text)))

            # Assign Text
            if len(bt1.text) == 0: bt1.text = self.text
            elif len(bt2.text) == 0: bt2.text = self.text 

            # Assign Opacity
            if bt2.opacity == 1: bt3.opacity = 1
            elif bt1.opacity == 1: bt2.opacity = 1
            elif bt1.opacity == 0: bt1.opacity = 1

    Button:
        pos: 200, 0
        text: 'C'
        on_press:
            print("Button {} pressed".format(self.text))

            # Assign Opacity
            if bt2.opacity == 1: bt3.opacity = 1
            elif bt1.opacity == 1: bt2.opacity = 1
            elif bt1.opacity == 0: bt1.opacity = 1
'''))
```

### Output - Change Button's Text

[image: Img01 - Button A pressed 3 times]
[image: Img02 - Button A & B pressed]
[image: Img03 - Button B, A & C pressed]

## Solution - Change Button's Opacity

When button A is pressed, check if bt1's opacity is equal to 0. If it's true then change it to 1. If it's false then change bt2's opacity from 0 to 1.

### Snippets

```
Button:
    pos: 0, 0
    text: 'A' 
    on_press: 
        if bt1.opacity == 0: bt1.opacity = 1
        elif bt1.opacity == 1: bt2.opacity = 1
```

### Example - Change Button's Opacity

#### main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
FloatLayout:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 100

    Button:
        id: bt1
        text: 'bt1'
        pos: 200, 300
        opacity: 0 
        on_press: self.opacity = 0
    Button:
        id: bt2
        text: 'bt2'
        pos: 300, 300
        opacity: 0
        on_press: self.opacity = 0

    Button:
        pos: 0, 0
        text: 'A' 
        on_press:
            if bt1.opacity == 0: bt1.opacity = 1
            elif bt1.opacity == 1: bt2.opacity = 1
'''))
```

### Output - Solution 1

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Button1 Displayed when Button A clicked]
[image: Img03 - Button2 Displayed when Button A clicked again]

Comment: thanks for your reply. However the issue on doing it is that once I press the button A again the bt1 gets back to opacity  = 0 and it should keep as 1. any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I have updated my post with `bt1.opacity = 1 if bt1.opacity == 0 else 1`

Comment: You are most welcome. Please remember to mark it as close. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I'm also trying to do the following:
on_press:
            bt2.opacity = 1 if bt1.opacity == 1 else 0
            bt1.opacity = 1 if bt1.opacity == 0 else 1
            bt2.text = self.text if bt2.text == '' else self.text
            bt1.text = self.text if bt1.text == '' else self.text

So, when I press the button A it should change the bt1 text to A and when I press the button B it should change the bt2 text to B however it changes both once it would changes only the respective button.

Comment: @GustavoMenezes: Please refer to my updated post for your second question.

Comment: if i press the button B first it should change the bt1 text to B, same as for button A, so the bt1 should show the text of the button I press, same as to bt2...I have tried too many expressions/codes.. no success!!!!

Comment: Updated post with *if...elif..* statements. Please check it out.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted. ***To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.*** Thank you.